# How to apply marquee to the Button programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, button, textview, android-button

I'm trying to add the marquee to my alert button(Negative button) text. This is the code:

```
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Dont showDont showDont showDont showDont showDont showDont showDont show",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    builder.setNeutralButton("Dont show", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Neutral", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertBox = builder.create();

    alertBox.show();

        Button button = alertBox.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        if(button==null){
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button is NULL",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {         
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), button.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             button.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
             button.setMaxLines(1);
             button.setSelected(true);
             button.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(10);
        }
```

I also tried to add the following lines:

```
button.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
```

but it didn't display the text of the button itself. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please..

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Dont showDont showDont showDont showDont showDont showDont showDont show",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    builder.setNeutralButton("Dont show", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked Neutral", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    final AlertDialog alertBox = builder.create();
    alertBox.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            Button posBtn =alertBox.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            Button negBtn =alertBox.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            Button neuBtn =alertBox.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);


            LinearLayout.LayoutParams posParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) posBtn.getLayoutParams();
            posParams.weight = 1;
            posParams.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams negParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) negBtn.getLayoutParams();
            negParams.weight = 1;
            negParams.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams neuParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) neuBtn.getLayoutParams();
            neuParams.weight = 1;
            neuParams.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

            posBtn.setLayoutParams(posParams);
            negBtn.setLayoutParams(negParams);
            neuBtn.setLayoutParams(neuParams);
        }
    });

    alertBox.show();
```